# How to trigger a BAT file on Shutdown Button Click?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-desktop

Windows 10's default "Shutdown" option keeps the open apps available on the next startup. So I've been using a BAT file with the simple line `shutdown -s -f -t 0`.

How can I make my shutdown button to trigger this command? Or is it even possible?

Comment: In UWP, this is not the recommended practice. Applications should not interfere with system behavior. In addition, in Native UWP, you cannot use `Process` to run bat files, which is not safe.